# Jquery Smooth Scroll - Prevent it from scrolling to top first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to add some smooth scrolling for my internal links. To be more specific, I have a floating top menu where these links are. When clicking on them I land on the respective section on my page and all smooth. The problem is however not scrolling up but rather down. If I scroll down once im on the top of the page then it works but scrolling further down then wont work because the script forces the user to scroll all the way up first before it reaches the destination. For example I have 3 links: Home, About and Contact. I can scroll down to about but if I then click on contact the beforementioned happens.

Here is my jsfiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/25cpLLtv/1/

The problem seems to be `'scrollTop': $target.offset().top`

Im really desperate as im trying to solve this the entire day.

Comment: your jsfiddle has no html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var t = $(this.hash).offset().top;
      $('.wrapper').animate({
            scrollTop: t,
       }, 1000);
    });
 });
```

Chekc the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miike21/25cpLLtv/3/)